# File items returned from Forge API query that don't appear in the BIM360 portal (i.e. they do not appear to exist except via query)

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there an explanation for why I would see file items under a particular folder when querying them via Forge API (I'm actually using the .NET Forge API client provided by Autodesk, specifically `FoldersAPI.GetFolderContents()` to retrieve items under the folder) but cannot see them when viewed through the portal, either under the same sign-in or even under account admin sign-in?

Is there also an explanation for why I would see under the same folder three seemingly identical copies of the files reporting different item ids and slightly different creation times but otherwise identical (even down to the versions they're reporting when querying the item versions).

I would post an example of the data of two items that are behaving in this manner, but due to IP concerns I can't post it here. Is there anything obvious I should be looking out for in troubleshooting this situation? I've confirmed that the items are not reporting `hidden` true or anything of the sort so it's not because they're hidden (if that's what that the property means).

Perhaps I should submit a bug report privately?

Answer (score 0):

On further investigation I've found that the folders the items were under are indeed different but they had the same name and same parent folder name (but different parent parent folder name). The report I was reading off was making it look like they were coming from the same folder. A wild goose chase led on by same named files and folders.

So really the question is now invalid.